# Create Oracle Trigger to execute PL/SQL program when row is inserted to table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a trigger in Oracle 11g, that is fired when a row is inserted to the table DLGPROD.INV_CHEMICAL when the value for the BATCHTYPE column is equal to 'STANDARD'.

The trigger will execute a PL/SQL program called SYS.STDEMAIL

When I try to call the STDEMAIL program, I get PLS-00331 illegal reference.

I am pretty new to working with triggers or PL/SQL, and I can't figure out how to tell the trigger #1 - to only fire when  a row is updated AND the BATCHTYPE column value is 'STANDARD', and #2 - how to correctly call the PL/SQL program called STDEMAIL belonging to the SYS schema.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written?

Comment: And the definition of the `sys.stdemail` procedure (I assume it's a procedure not a function).  Probably not related to your error but creating objects in the `SYS` schema is frowned upon by Oracle and should be avoided.  There are various ways that PL/SQL behaves differently in the `SYS` schema than it does elsewhere that also occasionally bite unwary developers.  Creating an appropriately powerful account that can own this sort of code is, by far, the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm)

#1 Here you can see that `Emp_tab` is the table you are watching, and `Sal` is a column. Using the `new` keyword as in `new.Sal` you can check the new inserted value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Log_salary_increase
AFTER UPDATE ON Emp_tab
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.Sal > 1000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Emp_log (Emp_id, Log_date, New_salary, Action)
       VALUES (:new.Empno, SYSDATE, :new.SAL, 'NEW SAL');
END;
```

#2 You can use the `call` keyword to execute an existing procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logontrig AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE 
-- Just call an existing procedure. The ORA_LOGIN_USER is a function
-- that returns information about the event that fired the trigger.
CALL foo (ora_login_user)
/
```